# PrimeNG Tree Drag&Drop with template not working

Tags: angular, primeng

I want to use the pDraggable and pDroppable on the items of my tree. I know that there's built in functionality for that, but I want to run some custom validation logic for which I need the drop events of pDroppable. So here is my code:

```
            <div class="ui-g-9">
            <p-tree          
                selectionMode="single"        
                droppableNodes="true"           
                [(selection)]="treeSelectedItem"
                [loading]="deepPerm == null"
                [value]="deepPerm | permissions" 
                [style]="{'height':'630px'}"
                [contextMenu]="cm"                    
                (onNodeContextMenuSelect)="context($event)">

                    <ng-template let-node pTemplate="default">
                        <div pDroppable="roledrop"
                            (onDragOver)="dragOver($event)"
                            (onDrop)="drop($event)">
                            <span>
                                {{node.label}}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </ng-template>

            </p-tree>
            <p-contextMenu #cm [model]="tblCtxMenuItems"></p-contextMenu>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-3">
            <p-tree            
                selectionMode="multiple"                                                                            
                [value]="roles" 
                [style]="{'height':'630px'}">

                <ng-template let-node pTemplate="default">                        
                    <span 
                        pDraggable="roledrop" 
                        (onDragStart)="dragStart($event,node)">
                            {{node.label}}
                    </span>                        
                </ng-template>

            </p-tree>
        </div>
```

I get the drag event, but I'm neither able to drop the item on the droppable from the other tree nor will I get any event from the droppable. It seems like the draggable is not even leaving the bounds of it's tree. I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but I really can't find my mistake. I'd be happy for any help. 
 

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: were you able to get this working?

Comment: Unfortunately not